# Use of abbreviation / acronym

Tags: discussion

I am aware many users/members in Stack Overflow use abbreviation such as "SO" for Stack Overflow.

However, new users may look at "SO" and can get confused and may automatically assume it's the word "so" (adverb). Would it be a better idea if people start using full stops for new users to indicate "SO" is in fact an abbreviation by saying "S.O." instead?

I know users who have been in Stack Overflow can naturally pick up and process most, if not all, the abbreviations quickly.  But as I have mentioned, there are quite a number of people who still get confused by this.

Comment: SO is capitalised, which implies it's an acronym - Stack Overflow. so will _never_ have a capital O, so it's easy to distinguish between them.

Comment: Yes, I know. However, there is still people who use them without capital letter. That's one of my point.

Comment: That's more unclear and I personally would probably be confused out of context. But not much you can do to correct someone who's unclear besides say "huh?"... or edit... or flag... or downvote.

Comment: S.O. is even more confusing than SO I.M.O, so...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a user-driven convention. We didn't have a big meeting where we decided to use "SO" to stand for "Stack Overflow," rather, a bunch of people got lazy and started typing "SO" and said "meh, they'll figure it out."

Also, you're going to have a struggling career in software development if you can't figure out when things are abbreviations and take some educated guesses as to what they might be short for.

So yes, you're right, but more importantly "meh." Writers should in general go out of their way to write things clearer to read than they are lazy to write, but we can't do much to enforce this, and it's a good thing they settle on convention rather than make up their own things each time.

Comment: And as you know, there is previous 'Question' in meta stack overflow that received more than 3 negative vote by just asking that. But yeah, it's matter of people figuring out and getting used it...

Comment: @user3315821 what question?

Comment: To be pedantic SO is not an abbreviation, it's an acronym.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222577/whats-so-on-election-board

Comment: @ben - Isn't acronym still an abbreviation?

Comment: No @user3315821, [though it's sometimes misrepresented as such.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation)

Comment: @ben, from your link: "An abbreviation is a shortening by any method...However, normally, acronyms are regarded as a subgroup of abbreviations"